# C reshape 1d to 2d

Tags: c

I want to reshape an array of length L to one of MxN, however rather than create new memory by copying the elements over in for loops I'd like to do some pointer casting to allow me to access the array with double subscripting (array[X][Y]) .

I've googled around for ages and couldn't find anything helpful.

Any help would really be appreciated.

EDIT: The array of interest is on the heap not stack.

Comment: You have to copy, or suffer undefined b.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pointer casting doesn't seem like a good idea here. But if the number of columns is known before run-time, one option I often encounter is to simply define a macro e.g.

```
#define arrayName(i,j) arrayName[((i)*N) + (j)]
```

Or

```
 #define ELEMENT(arrayName, i,j) (arrayName)[((i)*N) + (j)]
```

if you want it to be more flexible.

Comment: This is the correct solution. Keep the same type(!), just index it differently.

Answer (score 2):

`union`s are your friends:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define M 5
#define N 4

typedef union {
    int a1[M * N];
    int a2[M][N];
} U;

int main()
{
    U u;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < M * N; ++i)
    {
        u.a1[i] = i;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < M; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        {
            printf("%8d", u.a2[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can i safely modify the data through both references to the memory?

Comment: Yes, this is expressly permitted in C99/C11.

Answer (score 0):

`typedef`s are your friends:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define M 5
#define N 4

typedef int Array1D[M * N];
typedef int Array2D[M][N];

int main()
{
    Array1D *a1 = malloc(sizeof(*a1));
    Array2D *a2 = (Array2D *)a1;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < M * N; ++i)
    {
        (*a1)[i] = i;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < M; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        {
            printf("%8d", (*a2)[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(a1);

    return 0;
}
```

Note: above code has now been updated to use heap allocation so as not to break strict aliasing rules.

Comment: This will violate strict aliasing and cause ub, especially since you are using stack memory.

Comment: okay my memory here is on the heap, is this still a good solution if i just keep the casting rather than the typedefs?

Comment: @chris You can get away with it if you use the heap and do not reference the array with the old pointer. But I still wouldn't do it, unless you know what you are doing and/or writing a memory allocator.

Comment: @chris It depends on usage, you might still break strict aliasing. You certainly *will* if you refer to the old array with with a different type.

Comment: @2501: point taken regarding strict aliasing, but I don't see why it makes any difference as to where the memory is allocated ?

Comment: @PaulR There is a line in the standard where it says that you can do whatever you want with heap mem as long as you don't violate s.a. and alignment, but the stack variables must not be messed with, even with if those requirements are met. Can't find it right now.

Comment: @2501: interesting - I've never come across that before - could you give me a pointer to the relevant section in the standard?

Comment: c11: 6.2.4.,p1 Determines the storage allocation( memory ), memory returned by malloc is described by as: allocated. Then you have 6.5. p6 which describes types. The gist is:( talking about allocated mem only, and ignoring alignment ) once you **write** to mem with a type, it gets that type. If you **read** that mem with a different type you get s.a. violation. There is no circumventing this( ignoring unions for a moment ). However you can **write** into that mem. with a different type and it becomes of that type instead. But *then* you cannot read with the old type anymore.

Comment: Note that you have to write with the new type before you can read with the new type, and you are only allowed that with allocated memory.

Comment: Interesting, thanks, especially since reading and writing different elements in a union is allowed for in C99/C11 onwards, and there isn't much difference between unions and the above type punning, essentially. Perhaps I'll post another answer using a union and delete this one.

Comment: Right, in the above example a union might work, but currently it is still violating s.a.

Comment: OK - I modified it to use a heap allocation - but that's still UB ?

Comment: Yes, you are reading with a different type. `printf("%8d", (*a2)[i][j]);`

Comment: OK - many thanks - I've posted a `union` version of this answer now - I'll leave this answer here for historical interest.

Comment: Ok, great, I don't use them but imo the union approach is valid as long as the alignments are the same and there are no trap representations. In this case there are obviously no such problems.

Answer (score 0):

By the way if you want it super dynamic (as in no sizes are known at compile-time) you can do this by not copying all the values but by creating an index for the 2nd dimension like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int FULL = 100;
const int X = 10;
const int Y = 10;

int *dim1;
int **nested;

int main(void) {
    dim1 = malloc(sizeof(int)*FULL);
    nested = malloc(sizeof(int*)*X);
    for(int i=0; i<X;i++)
    {
        nested[i] = &dim1[Y*i];
    }
    dim1[15] = 42;
    printf("nested[1][5]: %d",nested[1][5]);

    free(nested);
    free(dim1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but I think you have X and Y the wrong way round ?

Comment: @RaulR depends on how you order it, this is column-major in memory.

Comment: Sure - but unless you're interfacing with FORTRAN or something else that's column-major then row-major would be preferable, I would have thought ?

Comment: @PaulR I guess it depends on how you'd be traversing it. If you take OpenGL for example, there they have their matrices in column-major. But to be honest the only reason why I ordered it this way in the example was so that I could do `[X][Y]` instead of `[Y][X]`